# Why can a transaction use more gas than what's attached?

Tags: nearprotocol

You can [call this simple counter contract with 1Tgas attached](https://raen.dev/admin/#/counter.raendev.testnet/Decrement?data=%257B%2522args%2522%253A%257B%257D%252C%2522options%2522%253A%257B%2522attachedDeposit%2522%253A%25220%2522%252C%2522gas%2522%253A%25221000000000000%2522%257D%257D) and it works.

And you'll see that both [NEAR Explorer](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/37rtgj5TgCeHj8tPaqW8eyGNmFtCrJrTwb1H5mQch396) and [nearblocks.io](https://testnet.nearblocks.io/txns/37rtgj5TgCeHj8tPaqW8eyGNmFtCrJrTwb1H5mQch396) agree that you *attached* only 1 Tgas but somehow *used* 5 Tgas.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Reading through these two chapters may be useful to understand the concepts:

- transactions https://docs.near.org/concepts/basics/transactions/overview
- gas https://docs.near.org/concepts/basics/transactions/gas

I'm by no means an expert, so this answer is a guess more than anything.

When a user calls a method on your contract, they are automatically deducted a fixed amount (gas) set by the [contract configurations](https://docs.near.org/concepts/basics/transactions/gas#the-cost-of-common-actions). For example

- `action_function_call_send_sir: 2_319_861_500_000`
- `action_function_call_execution: 2_319_861_500_000`
- `action_receipt_creation_send_sir: 108_059_500_000`

With these assumptions, the attached gas doesn't need to be higher than the gas used. If the total sum of `"automatically deducted gas" + "attached gas"` is more than what's actually burned, you'll get a refund.

From your transaction, you are refunded 0.00005Ⓝ. If you try to attach even less gas, e.g. 579279990000, you'll still be able to call the method, and you'll be refunded a little less 0.00001Ⓝ ([See this transaction](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/AoemL3VY7sweAeffSzRFi6wdH1dYJviw83k7HqDv1wTN))